# How to constrain label/element to tab bar?

Tags: swift, storyboard

I want my label above my tab bar, regardless of screen height. Currently, I'm only able to constrain it to the bottom of the screen (but not the tab bar, 2nd picture).

Alternatively, I tried constraining the label to the bottom at (50, a bigger number to account for the tab bar), but on different screen sizes it just doesn't look good.

Any way I can actually constrain the label to the tab bar (on storyboard/swift).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Constrain it to the **safe area**, not to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the constraint via storyboard.
-Add a bottom constraint
-Use the more to make it constraint to the view/NOT SAFE AREA